# Radio buttons appearing tiny in chrome and IE but appearing decent size in firefox

Tags: html, radio-button

Here is the link to my jsbin code snippet :
https://jsbin.com/bozovificu/edit?html

You will observe that even here the size of radio buttons is normal.

But in my chrome and IE they are very small and the size you saw in jsbin console is the same size as firefox(which I was expecting). Can anybody help as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: WEll i mean when you run that code as an independent html file then the size shrinks in chrome and IE. JSBIN will look same in all browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add some css, you have none

```css
#input-group {
  height: 60px;
}
input {
  height: 20px!important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
label {
  height: 57px!important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input,
label {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Network Port Configuration</p>
  <div id="input-group">
    <label for="cm">Connection Mode</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cm" id="static" value="static">
    <label for="static">Static</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cm" id="dhcp" value="dhcp">
    <label for="dhcp">DHCP</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the css can be added in style tags in the head section of your html document (<style> </style>)

Comment: thx a lot Rachel. It seems sites like JSBIN already include some css by default. Because it was displaying correctly only in firefox. Thanks for your prompt reply.